# jOOQ's record mapper converter losing timestamp precision

Tags: type-conversion, jooq

I have a column in the database of type `timestamp` which sometimes has a precision of nano seconds up to 6 digits e.g. `2012-09-17 18:47:52.123456` which I'm managing to retrieve the value for successfully (i.e. with the correct precision) in a jOOQ `record`. However, when converting this jOOQ `record` into a POJO using the `into` method, the value maps to a `LocalDateTime` with the fraction of the timestamp fraction being decreased to 3 i.e. `2012-09-17 18:47:52.123`.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or this is a genuine issue. Just wanted to ask, apart from implementing a custom [Converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.15/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/), is there any other solution which I can implement e.g. configuration?

Comment: The implementation uses `java.sql.Timestamp::toLocalDateTime` where the nanoseconds precision should be maintained. Can you show some code that helps reproducing this?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly a bug in jOOQ 3.15.1, 3.14.13, which should be fixed: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/12225

Instead of calling `Timestamp::toLocalDateTime`, which is nano second precision preserving, the reflective conversion first extracts `Timestamp::getTime` (the millisecond precision timestamp), and then converts that to a `LocalDateTime`, effectively truncating the timestamp to `TIMESTAMP(3)`.

This doesn't happen if you're using `SQLDataType.LOCALDATETIME` data types in your code generator, it is only an artefact of those `Record.into(Class)` calls, that use this reflective logic.

Comment: Thanks Lukas for such a prompt reply and for the detailed explanation. Much appreciated. Will upgrade to the latest version.